# I have an issue with pdftron integration

Tags: android, pdf, sdk, pdftron

I have an issue with pdf tron sdk integration I 've tried alone and that did not worked so i tried to run one of their samples but I ve always had 5 failed to resolve file error. They're documentation is not easy to read AND I did not undersand how to integrate their sdk via gradle or manually (I ve tried both). So If some one Had fully integrated their sdk I hope if they could send me a git hub repositorie or help with my issue.
ps : I am on android studio 3.0.1
this is a screenshot: [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sCEF.png)

Comment: if you know other apis show me

Comment: Sorry to hear you found our documentation difficult. We would really appreciate feedback so we could improve our documentation. At the bottom of all our documentation pages is a form to provide feedback. Perhaps you could let us know what sections were not easy to read, or anything else you would like us to know.

Answer (score 1):

To get the project running, you need to click **Build** -> **Clean Project** as described in step 4 of the tutorial: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/android/guides/faq/run-in-android-studio/